# Unable to download Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't seem to download Android Studio at all. I go to the official download page of AS, but nothing happens. I get no Pop-ups or nothing, and my internet connection is fine. Please help.

Comment: i also accepted all the agreements too, by the way.

Comment: Please give more information about your problem, thanks

Comment: Just tried, works fine on Windows and Mac. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @TheSilence17 have you tried [from here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)?

Comment: okay so i get to the devoloping page of android, it then says download android studio. i click it, then it says before installing Android Studio i must agree to the terms and conditions, i click agree, then the button for downloading it comes up. i click that. i brifly comes up with a page saying, please wait while Android Studio is downloading. then it goes to a page saying how to open it. The problem is i have not even downloaded it at all. no pop ups blocked or anything.

Comment: @M.Mariscal Yes thats the page i was on

Comment: And what is your os?

Comment: My os is Windows 7

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it's not really a programming question, but more of a technical problem.

Comment: This is because of OS detection bug. Firefox (Fedora Linux) merely return "5.0 (X11)" when query javascript `navigator.appVersion`, no such "Linux" term, but the green button checking is `if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Android")==-1)`

Comment: FWIW, I have [filed an issue to get this fixed](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223012). Use Chrome or Chromium as a workaround.

Comment: Its perfectly obvious what hes asking. He cant download android studio. And lots of people obviously understood what he asked.

Comment: go to the archives download and grab the latest stable version from there https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: @CommonsWare: How did you file that issue? It appears that this has cropped up again... I can download in Chromium but not Firefox. The page just fails to load

Comment: @mister-sir: The site was probably different six years ago. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697 should let you file an issue in the same component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try switching your explorer : Chrome -> Firefox or Firefox-> Chrome or Edge -> Chrome

Comment: i already tried explorer but okay i will try it

Comment: Not only explorer try : Chrome opera mozila firefox anything that works

Comment: okay i have tryed Firefox, it does not work

Comment: please help i honestly dont know what to do

Comment: How about trying to download from an alterantive source?  torrent?maybe this?http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5

Comment: just right click the download link, and choose "open on the new tab";  download starts.

Answer (score 13):

Strangely, I could actually reproduce this - the download wouldn't start, in Firefox only. However, when viewing the [downloads section of the page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#downloads), it does work. Just the big "Download" button at the top of the page does not work.

[Note: this particular issue seems to be fixed as of 2021; just download it as normal from here: https://developer.android.com/studio]

Comment: When clicked on download a table with different platform will appears, right click on link and open in new tab . I will start downloading.